# Unable to import mediaplayer module

Tags: import, pyqt, media-player, pyqt5

I want to build a simple mp3 player with Qt5 but I've not had much luck importing the required modules. How do I import Qt5 MediaPlayer? It seems like it is not available in pyqt5.

Here is how I attempted to do the import

```
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

the result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/ncodes/SkyDrive/Codes/Python/Experiment/py3.py", line 1, in <module>
  from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer
ImportError: cannot import name QMediaPlayer
```

I do not understand why QMediaPlayer cannot be imported because I know Qt5 has QMediaPlayer in QtMultimedia module.

Comment: I am looking for the exact same thing.  Very poor documentation on PyQt5, so I might just stay away from it completely

Comment: I agree with you. I hope I can find a solution soon

Answer (score 1):

there is no QMediaPlayer in PyQt5.QtMultimedia of current PyQt5

you can test by the following code

```
>>>import PyQt5.QtMultimedia 
>>>'QMediaPlayer' in [n for n in dir(PyQt5.QtMultimedia)]
```

Comment: It's somewhat annoying then that they've decided to call it a "Qt5" binding, when it's obviously not a complete Qt5 implementation

Comment: maybe a future version would be a real "Qt5" binding :)